# .Net Standard Library in .Net 4.6.2 project: System.Runtime assembly not found

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-standard

I have a .NET standard library which I would like to use in a .Net 4.6.2 project. The .Net standard library was installed via nuget. At runtime, I get the following error:

System.Runtime Version 4.1.0.0 not found

I read somewhere that you have to install the nuget package "NetStandard.Library" in this case. I did that but unfortunately it did not help.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add System.Runtime? If not - why not?

Comment: In my experience, It has always been so that nuget has automatically downloaded additional needed references. I could add System.Runtime manually and the error would disappear but then another error comes up (System.IO not found). It seems that the OpenCage library needs many additional references and it would be an endless story to add them all manually.

Comment: Then you have little experience. It may do so, but there are some conditions - which may well not be met here. Had to manually add references occasionally. And yes, pre dotnet core this DOES turn into an endless story.

Comment: Suggest to migrate your project to use the csproj 2017 format first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` to the StartUp project file (not the project file where the external library is used). Now it works :) Thanks.

Nuget package "NetStandard.Library" is still needed (in project file where the external library is used).